# RoboCopy not copying all files and folders

Tags: robocopy

This is a bit of an extension of this thread..
[Robocopy silently missing files](https://serverfault.com/questions/224442/robocopy-silently-missing-files)

I have a similar problem. I am using RoboCopy to copy files to a USB disk that will be transported to another location.

The log output is as follows:

Started : Thu Apr 26 04:33:18 2018

Source : \domain\Home\data\Users\User1\  (Network File Share)
     Dest : D:\User_Data\User1\  (USB Drive)

```
Files : *.*
```

Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1 /W:1

The log output reports:

```
            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :     22331     22331         0         0         0         0
Files :    226675    226675         0         0         0         0
Bytes :  94.972 g  94.972 g         0         0         0         0
Times :   7:05:25   6:52:13                       0:00:00   0:13:12

Speed :             4122958 Bytes/sec.
Speed :             235.917 MegaBytes/min.
```

However, a folder properties on the Network Share shows:
226319 files, 22275 folders

And a folder properties on the USB Drive

226613 files, 22322 folders

I need to account for the discrepancy..

We have also tried with various other switches..

/B (Backup)
/IA:ASH  (Hidden System Archive Set)

This made absolutely no difference.

The bit that is really strange is that NONE of the file and folder counts match up with the RoboCopy Log files. There are no errors or skipped files reported in the log output.

I am at a total loss. With 6 sample folders  checked at Source and Destination, 4 are OK, 1 has a 1 file discrepancy and there is this one which is just weird..

I really would welcome any suggestions. I have never had a problem with RoboCopy before, we are regular users of this program.

My only thought was whether the properties actually counts real folders and files or just entries in the FAT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your destination has MORE files than the source. Try replacing `/S /E` with `/MIR` or adding `/PURGE` to delete files from the destination that no longer exist on the source.
If that's not it... are the source and destination each formatted with the same type of file system?